# legacy tables: none-id field named id

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using a legacy database which has a field "usernr" as the primary key and a field "id" holding the user name. I added a mapping to get the usernr setup as the identifying property:

```
class User {
    Long usernr
    String id
    String password

    static mapping = {
        id name: 'usernr', generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'usernr']
    }
}
```

But a scaffolding controller is not showing the id field itself. Since "id" seems to be a reserved keyword for mapping, I'm not sure if there is any way to get this setup correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: As a workaround I upgraded to postgres 9.3 and create an auto-updatable view and used different fields names.

Comment: Yes you right, but reserved `id` it is not keyword. It is the same field and it added automatically.